# Getting Failed (exit code: 1). when running restore DB from a .tar file in pgAdmin4 postgresql 10.5

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, postgresql-10, mac-os-x

I'm taking an intro to SQL course and I can't get my very first database loaded. I have a file dvdrental.tar, I create a new database dvdrental > right click > Restore > Select File > Pick "Data" under Restore options, and I get the error below.

I'm on Mac OSX and the pgAmin instance is being loaded in Chrome if that helps. I've tried deleting and re-adding the database twice and I still get the same error. I also tried reinstalling pgAdmin and fully reinstalling postgresql including removing the user account. I just tried doing it on a fresh install in a Windows environment and I get the exact same error.

I've also completely rebooted the computer several times since then. I also just verified that other tar files and a sql file aren't working.
[image: Restore Error Failed (exit code: 1).]

[image: Details on Error]

Here's the full error, I have no idea what any of it means, as I'm brand new to SQL and just setting it up:

```
/Library/PostgreSQL/10/bin/pg_restore --host "localhost" --port "5432" --username "postgres" --no-password --dbname "dvdrental" --section=data --verbose "/Users/chasehippen/Downloads/Postgresql/dvdrental.tar"

    pg_restore: connecting to database for restore
    pg_restore: implied data-only restore
    pg_restore: processing data for table "public.actor"
    pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error while PROCESSING TOC:
    pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 2610; 0 16430 TABLE DATA actor postgres
    pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "actor" does not exist
        Command was: COPY actor (actor_id, first_name, last_name, last_update) FROM stdin;
    pg_restore: executing SEQUENCE SET actor_actor_id_seq
    pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 2643; 0 0 SEQUENCE SET actor_actor_id_seq postgres
    pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "actor_actor_id_seq" does not exist
    LINE 1: SELECT pg_catalog.setval('actor_actor_id_seq', 200, true);
                                     ^
        Command was: SELECT pg_catalog.setval('actor_actor_id_seq', 200, true);
    pg_restore: processing data for table "public.address"
    pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 2618; 0 16471 TABLE DATA address postgres
    pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "address" does not exist
        Command was: COPY address (address_id, address, address2, district, city_id, postal_code, phone, last_update) FROM stdin;
    pg_restore: executing SEQUENCE SET address_address_id_seq
    pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 2644; 0 0 SEQUENCE SET address_address_id_seq postgres
    pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "address_address_id_seq" does not exist
    LINE 1: SELECT pg_catalog.setval('address_address_id_seq', 605, true...
                                     ^
        Command was: SELECT pg_catalog.setval('address_address_id_seq', 605, true);
    pg_restore: processing data for table "public.category"
    pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 2612; 0 16437 TABLE DATA category postgres
    pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "category" does not exist
        Command was: COPY category (category_id, name, last_update) FROM stdin;
    pg_restore: executing SEQUENCE SET category_category_id_seq
    pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 2645; 0 0 SEQUENCE SET category_category_id_seq postgres
    pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "category_category_id_seq" does not exist
    LINE 1: SELECT pg_catalog.setval('category_category_id_seq', 16, tru...
                                     ^
        Command was: SELECT pg_catalog.setval('category_category_id_seq', 16, true);
    pg_restore: processing data for table "public.city"
    pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 2620; 0 16478 TABLE DATA city postgres
    pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "city" does not exist
        Command was: COPY city (city_id, city, country_id, last_update) FROM stdin;
    pg_restore: executing SEQUENCE SET city_city_id_seq
    pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 2646; 0 0 SEQUENCE SET city_city_id_seq postgres
    pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "city_city_id_seq" does not exist
    LINE 1: SELECT pg_catalog.setval('city_city_id_seq', 600, true);
                                     ^
        Command was: SELECT pg_catalog.setval('city_city_id_seq', 600, true);
    pg_restore: processing data for table "public.country"
    pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 2622; 0 16485 TABLE DATA country postgres
    pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "country" does not exist
        Command was: COPY country (country_id, country, last_update) FROM stdin;
    pg_restore: executing SEQUENCE SET country_country_id_seq
    pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 2647; 0 0 SEQUENCE SET country_country_id_seq postgres
    pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "country_country_id_seq" does not exist
    LINE 1: SELECT pg_catalog.setval('country_country_id_seq', 109, true...
                                     ^
        Command was: SELECT pg_catalog.setval('country_country_id_seq', 109, true);
    pg_restore: processing data for table "public.customer"
    pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 2608; 0 16419 TABLE DATA customer postgres
    pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "customer" does not exist
        Command was: COPY customer (customer_id, store_id, first_name, last_name, email, address_id, activebool, create_date, last_update, active) FROM stdin;
    pg_restore: executing SEQUENCE SET customer_customer_id_seq
    pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 2648; 0 0 SEQUENCE SET customer_customer_id_seq postgres
    pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "customer_customer_id_seq" does not exist
    LINE 1: SELECT pg_catalog.setval('customer_customer_id_seq', 599, tr...
                                     ^
        Command was: SELECT pg_catalog.setval('customer_customer_id_seq', 599, true);
    pg_restore: processing data for table "public.film"
    pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 2614; 0 16444 TABLE DATA film postgres
    pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "film" does not exist
        Command was: COPY film (film_id, title, description, release_year, language_id, rental_duration, rental_rate, length, replacement_cost, rating, last_update, special_features, fulltext) FROM stdin;
    pg_restore: processing data for table "public.film_actor"
    pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 2615; 0 16456 TABLE DATA film_actor postgres
    pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "film_actor" does not exist
        Command was: COPY film_actor (actor_id, film_id, last_update) FROM stdin;
    pg_restore: processing data for table "public.film_category"
    pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 2616; 0 16460 TABLE DATA film_category postgres
    pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "film_category" does not exist
        Command was: COPY film_category (film_id, category_id, last_update) FROM stdin;
    pg_restore: executing SEQUENCE SET film_film_id_seq
    pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 2649; 0 0 SEQUENCE SET film_film_id_seq postgres
    pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "film_film_id_seq" does not exist
    LINE 1: SELECT pg_catalog.setval('film_film_id_seq', 1000, true);
                                     ^
        Command was: SELECT pg_catalog.setval('film_film_id_seq', 1000, true);
    pg_restore: processing data for table "public.inventory"
    pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 2624; 0 16502 TABLE DATA inventory postgres
    pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "inventory" does not exist
        Command was: COPY inventory (inventory_id, film_id, store_id, last_update) FROM stdin;
    pg_restore: executing SEQUENCE SET inventory_inventory_id_seq
    pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 2650; 0 0 SEQUENCE SET inventory_inventory_id_seq postgres
    pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "inventory_inventory_id_seq" does not exist
    LINE 1: SELECT pg_catalog.setval('inventory_inventory_id_seq', 4581,...
                                     ^
        Command was: SELECT pg_catalog.setval('inventory_inventory_id_seq', 4581, true);
    pg_restore: processing data for table "public.language"
    pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 2626; 0 16509 TABLE DATA language postgres
    pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "language" does not exist
        Command was: COPY language (language_id, name, last_update) FROM stdin;
    pg_restore: executing SEQUENCE SET language_language_id_seq
    pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 2651; 0 0 SEQUENCE SET language_language_id_seq postgres
    pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "language_language_id_seq" does not exist
    LINE 1: SELECT pg_catalog.setval('language_language_id_seq', 6, true...
                                     ^
        Command was: SELECT pg_catalog.setval('language_language_id_seq', 6, true);
    pg_restore: processing data for table "public.payment"
    pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 2628; 0 16521 TABLE DATA payment postgres
    pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "payment" does not exist
        Command was: COPY payment (payment_id, customer_id, staff_id, rental_id, amount, payment_date) FROM stdin;
    pg_restore: executing SEQUENCE SET payment_payment_id_seq
    pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 2652; 0 0 SEQUENCE SET payment_payment_id_seq postgres
    pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "payment_payment_id_seq" does not exist
    LINE 1: SELECT pg_catalog.setval('payment_payment_id_seq', 32098, tr...
                                     ^
        Command was: SELECT pg_catalog.setval('payment_payment_id_seq', 32098, true);
    pg_restore: processing data for table "public.rental"
    pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 2630; 0 16527 TABLE DATA rental postgres
    pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "rental" does not exist
        Command was: COPY rental (rental_id, rental_date, inventory_id, customer_id, return_date, staff_id, last_update) FROM stdin;
    pg_restore: executing SEQUENCE SET rental_rental_id_seq
    pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 2653; 0 0 SEQUENCE SET rental_rental_id_seq postgres
    pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "rental_rental_id_seq" does not exist
    LINE 1: SELECT pg_catalog.setval('rental_rental_id_seq', 16049, true...
                                     ^
        Command was: SELECT pg_catalog.setval('rental_rental_id_seq', 16049, true);
    pg_restore: processing data for table "public.staff"
    pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 2632; 0 16539 TABLE DATA staff postgres
    pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "staff" does not exist
        Command was: COPY staff (staff_id, first_name, last_name, address_id, email, store_id, active, username, password, last_update, picture) FROM stdin;
    pg_restore: executing SEQUENCE SET staff_staff_id_seq
    pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 2654; 0 0 SEQUENCE SET staff_staff_id_seq postgres
    pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "staff_staff_id_seq" does not exist
    LINE 1: SELECT pg_catalog.setval('staff_staff_id_seq', 2, true);
                                     ^
        Command was: SELECT pg_catalog.setval('staff_staff_id_seq', 2, true);
    pg_restore: processing data for table "public.store"
    pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 2634; 0 16550 TABLE DATA store postgres
    pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "store" does not exist
        Command was: COPY store (store_id, manager_staff_id, address_id, last_update) FROM stdin;
    pg_restore: executing SEQUENCE SET store_store_id_seq
    pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 2655; 0 0 SEQUENCE SET store_store_id_seq postgres
    pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "store_store_id_seq" does not exist
    LINE 1: SELECT pg_catalog.setval('store_store_id_seq', 2, true);
                                     ^
        Command was: SELECT pg_catalog.setval('store_store_id_seq', 2, true);
    WARNING: errors ignored on restore: 28
```

Comment: It's doing a data-only restore, so it's not creating the tables. I don't know how to tell pgadmin to do a full restore, but there's bound to be an option somewhere

Comment: Turns out I just didn't need the Data option and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by unchecking the Data option